# Splash Screen Asset Image not loading when flutter app is restarted

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I have a splash screen where I am calling a bunch of APIs and once all the API calls are successful, the app needs to go to the home screen.

**Code for Splash Screen**

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  static final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  Map<String, dynamic> _deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      // perform bunch of API calls here
      if (context.mounted) {
        navigate(context);
      }
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 100.w,
        height: 100.h,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(ImageConstants.splashBackGround),
            // fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  await dotenv.load(fileName: '.env.development');
  runApp(MyApp(appRouter: AppRouter()));
}
```

In the MaterialApp, I have the initialRoute set as the route for splash screen:

```
MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'InvestNation',
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          theme: ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                // statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
              ),
            ),
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          initialRoute: Routes.splash,
          onGenerateRoute: widget.appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
        ),
```

Where,

```
class Routes {
  static const String splash = '/';
}
```

**Issue faced**

When the app is installed for the first time, I am able to see the desired asset image. However, if I terminates the app and then relaunch it, I am only shown a white screen for the duration of the API calls and once the calls are complete I am taken to the desired home screen.

**Request**

I would like to know if I am making any mistake in my code which prevents me from seeing the asset image when the app is relaunched, and if so please share the solution for the same.